# LINQ in NEST framework for ElasticSearch

Tags: .net, linq, elasticsearch, nest

Can I use LINQ in NEST/ElasticSearch? If answer is YES where I can find documentation of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, NEST does not support LINQ.  However, there is [ElasticLINQ](https://github.com/CenturyLinkCloud/ElasticLINQ), which does.